# my executable file is so big even though my main doesn't call anything (C++)

Tags: c++

i'm a beginner coder here.
so I have a file with main that looks like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Helper.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout<<argc<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and I linked it with 2 other .cpp
I'm just wondering why the executable comes out to be so big (330kb)
when the main doesn't even call any functions.
are all the methods and variables in my other 2 .cpp wrapped up in the executable even though
I haven't actually called any functions? I only have 1 extern int declared. no static functions

this is the makefile call I used to compile

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS =-Wall -pedantic -g -O0 -std=c++11
test: Helper.cpp Helper.hpp HCTree.cpp HCTree.hpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o test test.cpp Helper.cpp HCTree.cpp
```

and I call "make test"

Comment: You're compiling with no optimization (-O0) and with debug symbols (-g), so it's bound to be bigger than it would seem. Also, `cout` is a function call so it actually does call something.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman A small correction: `cout` is an object, not a function.

Comment: @Ron True, should have said that the stream operator `<<` on `cout` will issue a call instead.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I suggest you turn your first comment into an answer. Also note there are multiple translation units involved.

Comment: Why the `#include "Helper.hpp"` and compiling also Helper.cpp and HCTree.cpp? They could have code that is being called before `main()`, so we can't give a definitive answer if you only show a third of the code.

Comment: @WernerHenze I didn't want to overload it to make things hard to read, ok I will upload the rest of the code, make be it will be clearer.
I don't know how to upload just the files, they are quite big.
thank u guys for the help. I will take this down in a bit and figure it out some how.

Comment: Your executable calls the `<<` operator of `cout`, for a start, and therefore everything it depends on, transitively until closure. This is non-trivial. Not to mention whatever is implied by `#include Helper.hpp` and linking `Helper.cpp` and `HCTree.cpp`.

Comment: @darres If the problem also occurs without `Helper.hpp`, `Helper.cpp` and `HCTree.cpp`, then just omit them. No need to show more code than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that your binary will include parts of the standard libraries and the symbol maps, even if you compile the extreme trivial case as follows:

#### main.cpp

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

```
~# g++ -Wall -pedantic -g -O0 -std=c++11 -o test main.cpp
~# ls -ltr
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jordan jordan 10264 Mar  1 08:14 test
```

after compiling it, my binary is around 10k. If you are compiling it for linux, you can see what is in the binary by calling `readelf -a` or by examining the symbols in the file with `nm`.

```
~# readelf -a test
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           AArch64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x610
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          8152 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         9
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         33
  Section header string table index: 32

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS         0000000000000238  00000238
       000000000000001b  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 2] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE             0000000000000254  00000254
       0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 3] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE             0000000000000278  00000278
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH         0000000000000298  00000298
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       5     0     8
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM           00000000000002b8  000002b8
       00000000000000d8  0000000000000018   A       6     3     8
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB           0000000000000390  00000390
       0000000000000082  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM           0000000000000412  00000412
       0000000000000012  0000000000000002   A       5     0     2
  [ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED          0000000000000428  00000428
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       6     1     8
  [ 9] .rela.dyn         RELA             0000000000000448  00000448
       00000000000000f0  0000000000000018   A       5     0     8
  [10] .rela.plt         RELA             0000000000000538  00000538
       0000000000000060  0000000000000018  AI       5    21     8
  [11] .init             PROGBITS         0000000000000598  00000598
       0000000000000014  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS         00000000000005b0  000005b0
       0000000000000060  0000000000000010  AX       0     0     16
  [13] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000000610  00000610
       00000000000001ac  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     8
  [14] .fini             PROGBITS         00000000000007bc  000007bc
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [15] .rodata           PROGBITS         00000000000007cc  000007cc
       0000000000000004  0000000000000004  AM       0     0     4
  [16] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS         00000000000007d0  000007d0
       0000000000000044  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [17] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         0000000000000818  00000818
       00000000000000dc  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [18] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY       0000000000010d88  00000d88
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [19] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY       0000000000010d90  00000d90
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [20] .dynamic          DYNAMIC          0000000000010d98  00000d98
       00000000000001f0  0000000000000010  WA       6     0     8
  [21] .got              PROGBITS         0000000000010f88  00000f88
       0000000000000078  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [22] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000011000  00001000
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [23] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000011010  00001010
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
  [24] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00001010
       000000000000002a  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [25] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000103a
       0000000000000030  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [26] .debug_info       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000106a
       0000000000000098  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [27] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00001102
       0000000000000078  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [28] .debug_line       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000117a
       0000000000000050  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [29] .debug_str        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000011ca
       00000000000000bf  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [30] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00001290
       0000000000000900  0000000000000018          31    73     8
  [31] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00001b90
       000000000000030d  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [32] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  00001e9d
       000000000000013a  0000000000000000           0     0     1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  p (processor specific)

There are no section groups in this file.

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R      0x8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000000238
                 0x000000000000001b 0x000000000000001b  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x00000000000008f4 0x00000000000008f4  R E    0x10000
  LOAD           0x0000000000000d88 0x0000000000010d88 0x0000000000010d88
                 0x0000000000000288 0x0000000000000290  RW     0x10000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000000d98 0x0000000000010d98 0x0000000000010d98
                 0x00000000000001f0 0x00000000000001f0  RW     0x8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000000254
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x00000000000007d0 0x00000000000007d0 0x00000000000007d0
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000000d88 0x0000000000010d88 0x0000000000010d88
                 0x0000000000000278 0x0000000000000278  R      0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00
   01     .interp
   02     .interp .note.gnu.build-id .note.ABI-tag .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame
   03     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .data .bss
   04     .dynamic
   05     .note.gnu.build-id .note.ABI-tag
   06     .eh_frame_hdr
   07
   08     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got

Dynamic section at offset 0xd98 contains 27 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x598
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x7bc
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x10d88
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x10d90
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x298
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x390
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x2b8
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              130 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000015 (DEBUG)              0x0
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x10f88
 0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           96 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
 0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0x538
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x448
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             240 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001e (FLAGS)              BIND_NOW
 0x000000006ffffffb (FLAGS_1)            Flags: NOW PIE
 0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x428
 0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         1
 0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x412
 0x000000006ffffff9 (RELACOUNT)          6
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0

Relocation section '.rela.dyn' at offset 0x448 contains 10 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000010d88  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    718
000000010d90  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    6d0
000000010fc8  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    7b8
000000010fe8  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    738
000000010ff0  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    71c
000000011008  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    11008
000000010fd0  000300000401 R_AARCH64_GLOB_DA 0000000000000000 _ITM_deregisterTMClone + 0
000000010fd8  000400000401 R_AARCH64_GLOB_DA 0000000000000000 __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.17 + 0
000000010fe0  000600000401 R_AARCH64_GLOB_DA 0000000000000000 __gmon_start__ + 0
000000010ff8  000800000401 R_AARCH64_GLOB_DA 0000000000000000 _ITM_registerTMCloneTa + 0

Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0x538 contains 4 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000010fa0  000400000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.17 + 0
000000010fa8  000500000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.17 + 0
000000010fb0  000600000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 __gmon_start__ + 0
000000010fb8  000700000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 abort@GLIBC_2.17 + 0

The decoding of unwind sections for machine type AArch64 is not currently supported.

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 9 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000598     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   11
     2: 0000000000011000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   22
     3: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTab
     4: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.17 (2)
     5: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.17 (2)
     6: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
     7: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND abort@GLIBC_2.17 (2)
     8: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_registerTMCloneTable

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 96 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000238     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
     2: 0000000000000254     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2
     3: 0000000000000278     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3
     4: 0000000000000298     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4
     5: 00000000000002b8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5
     6: 0000000000000390     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6
     7: 0000000000000412     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7
     8: 0000000000000428     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    8
     9: 0000000000000448     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    9
    10: 0000000000000538     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   10
    11: 0000000000000598     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   11
    12: 00000000000005b0     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   12
    13: 0000000000000610     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   13
    14: 00000000000007bc     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   14
    15: 00000000000007cc     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   15
    16: 00000000000007d0     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   16
    17: 0000000000000818     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   17
    18: 0000000000010d88     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   18
    19: 0000000000010d90     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   19
    20: 0000000000010d98     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   20
    21: 0000000000010f88     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   21
    22: 0000000000011000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   22
    23: 0000000000011010     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   23
    24: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   24
    25: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   25
    26: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   26
    27: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   27
    28: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   28
    29: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   29
    30: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linu
    31: 0000000000000278     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 $d
    32: 0000000000000610     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 $x
    33: 00000000000007cc     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 $d
    34: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linu
    35: 0000000000000648     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 $x
    36: 0000000000000648    20 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 call_weak_fn
    37: 0000000000000598     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   11 $x
    38: 00000000000007bc     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 $x
    39: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linu
    40: 00000000000005a4     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   11 $x
    41: 00000000000007c4     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 $x
    42: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS crtstuff.c
    43: 0000000000000660     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 $x
    44: 0000000000000660     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 deregister_tm_clones
    45: 0000000000000690     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 register_tm_clones
    46: 0000000000011008     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   22 $d
    47: 00000000000006d0     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 __do_global_dtors_aux
    48: 0000000000011010     1 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   23 completed.9126
    49: 0000000000010d90     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   19 $d
    50: 0000000000010d90     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   19 __do_global_dtors_aux_fin
    51: 0000000000000718     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 frame_dummy
    52: 0000000000010d88     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   18 $d
    53: 0000000000010d88     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   18 __frame_dummy_init_array_
    54: 000000000000082c     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   17 $d
    55: 0000000000011010     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   23 $d
    56: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS main.cpp
    57: 000000000000071c     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 $x
    58: 0000000000000890     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   17 $d
    59: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS elf-init.oS
    60: 0000000000000738     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 $x
    61: 00000000000008a8     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   17 $d
    62: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS crtstuff.c
    63: 00000000000008f0     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   17 $d
    64: 00000000000008f0     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   17 __FRAME_END__
    65: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS
    66: 0000000000010d90     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   18 __init_array_end
    67: 0000000000010d98     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS _DYNAMIC
    68: 0000000000010d88     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   18 __init_array_start
    69: 00000000000007d0     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
    70: 0000000000010fc0     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
    71: 0000000000000598     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   11 _init
    72: 00000000000005b0     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   12 $x
    73: 00000000000007b8     4 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 __libc_csu_fini
    74: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTab
    75: 0000000000011000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT   22 data_start
    76: 0000000000011010     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 __bss_start__
    77: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.1
    78: 0000000000011018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 _bss_end__
    79: 0000000000011010     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   22 _edata
    80: 00000000000007bc     0 FUNC    GLOBAL HIDDEN    14 _fini
    81: 0000000000011018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 __bss_end__
    82: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_
    83: 0000000000011000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   22 __data_start
    84: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
    85: 0000000000011008     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL HIDDEN    22 __dso_handle
    86: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND abort@@GLIBC_2.17
    87: 00000000000007cc     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 _IO_stdin_used
    88: 0000000000000738   124 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 __libc_csu_init
    89: 0000000000011018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 _end
    90: 0000000000000610     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _start
    91: 0000000000011018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 __end__
    92: 0000000000011010     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 __bss_start
    93: 000000000000071c    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 main
    94: 0000000000011010     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL HIDDEN    22 __TMC_END__
    95: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_registerTMCloneTable

Version symbols section '.gnu.version' contains 9 entries:
 Addr: 0x0000000000000412  Offset: 0x000412  Link: 5 (.dynsym)
  000:   0 (*local*)       0 (*local*)       0 (*local*)       0 (*local*)
  004:   2 (GLIBC_2.17)    2 (GLIBC_2.17)    0 (*local*)       2 (GLIBC_2.17)
  008:   0 (*local*)

Version needs section '.gnu.version_r' contains 1 entry:
 Addr: 0x0000000000000428  Offset: 0x000428  Link: 6 (.dynstr)
  000000: Version: 1  File: libc.so.6  Cnt: 1
  0x0010:   Name: GLIBC_2.17  Flags: none  Version: 2

Displaying notes found in: .note.gnu.build-id
  Owner                Data size    Description
  GNU                  0x00000014   NT_GNU_BUILD_ID (unique build ID bitstring)
    Build ID: 3e05092df57e4b081d4823e60f0e74fa226ac79f

Displaying notes found in: .note.ABI-tag
  Owner                Data size    Description
  GNU                  0x00000010   NT_GNU_ABI_TAG (ABI version tag)
    OS: Linux, ABI: 3.7.0
```

```
~# nm -a test
nm -a test
0000000000000000 a
                 U abort@@GLIBC_2.17
0000000000011010 b .bss
0000000000011018 B __bss_end__
0000000000011018 B _bss_end__
0000000000011010 B __bss_start
0000000000011010 B __bss_start__
0000000000000648 t call_weak_fn
0000000000000000 n .comment
0000000000011010 b completed.9126
0000000000000000 a crtstuff.c
0000000000000000 a crtstuff.c
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.17
0000000000011000 d .data
0000000000011000 D __data_start
0000000000011000 W data_start
0000000000000000 N .debug_abbrev
0000000000000000 N .debug_aranges
0000000000000000 N .debug_info
0000000000000000 N .debug_line
0000000000000000 N .debug_str
0000000000000660 t deregister_tm_clones
00000000000006d0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000010d90 d __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000011008 D __dso_handle
0000000000010d98 d .dynamic
0000000000010d98 a _DYNAMIC
0000000000000390 r .dynstr
00000000000002b8 r .dynsym
0000000000011010 D _edata
0000000000000818 r .eh_frame
00000000000007d0 r .eh_frame_hdr
0000000000000000 a elf-init.oS
0000000000011018 B __end__
0000000000011018 B _end
00000000000007bc t .fini
00000000000007bc T _fini
0000000000010d90 d .fini_array
0000000000000718 t frame_dummy
0000000000010d88 d __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
00000000000008f0 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000010fc0 a _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
00000000000007d0 r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
0000000000000298 r .gnu.hash
0000000000000412 r .gnu.version
0000000000000428 r .gnu.version_r
0000000000010f88 d .got
0000000000000598 t .init
0000000000000598 t _init
0000000000010d88 d .init_array
0000000000010d90 d __init_array_end
0000000000010d88 d __init_array_start
0000000000000238 r .interp
00000000000007cc R _IO_stdin_used
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
00000000000007b8 T __libc_csu_fini
0000000000000738 T __libc_csu_init
                 U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.17
000000000000071c T main
0000000000000000 a main.cpp
0000000000000278 r .note.ABI-tag
0000000000000254 r .note.gnu.build-id
00000000000005b0 t .plt
0000000000000690 t register_tm_clones
0000000000000448 r .rela.dyn
0000000000000538 r .rela.plt
00000000000007cc r .rodata
0000000000000610 T _start
0000000000000610 t .text
0000000000011010 D __TMC_END__
0000000000000000 a /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/crti.o
0000000000000000 a /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
0000000000000000 a /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o
```

You can lower the size by stripping the symbols as follows:

```
~# strip test
~# ls -ltr
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jordan jordan 6056 Mar  1 08:21 test
```

so the file went from 10k to 6k.